# serilog appSettings write to file in the same server path asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, appsettings, serilog

I have a serilog code and I want to move the configuration to the web.config file.

everything works fine but the problem is with the path of the file:

```
var logFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"EnBW.DokumentErfassung.Web-{Environment.MachineName}.log");
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.AppSettings();
```

I want to write the new file in the same server path,
the web.config code is:

```
<add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="log123-{Date}.txt" />
```

but the files saved has been saved in C:/program file/ .....

I want it to be saved in the same Domain path. what should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The app settings provider supports environment variables, so in *Global.asax.cs* before configuring the logger:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("BASEDIR", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

And use `%BASEDIR%` in config:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat"
     value="%BASEDIR%\logs\log-{Date}.txt" />
```

Comment: curious how this will work for multiple sites running on the same server/machine, surely the environment variable will be overwritten by each site?

Comment: No, environment variables are per-process (inherited from their parent process)

Comment: Ace thanks, well that's great to know. Perhaps this info should be added to the docs/wiki