# Environment variables not working in Serilog configuration

Tags: serilog

My web application contains 5 different ASP.Net Core Web apps and I am using Serilog for logging.  The configuration is managed through appsettings.config file.  I would like to specify the log folder path using environment variable, so that the specific setting need to be changed for all applications independently.  Something similar to below:

```
"WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%LOG_FOLDER%app1logs.json"
```

However, this model is not working i.e. logs are captured.  I checked and the %LOG_FOLDER% variable set it to "D:\Applicaiton\Logs\" global.  If I change the configuration to D:\Applicaiton\Logs\app1logs.json, logs are capturing.

Question: Are environment variables supported in Serilog configuration similar to the above.  Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: It does work in appsettings.json with Serilog.AspNetCore v7.0.0: `"path": "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\AppName\\Logs\\my.log"` In code - it does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [serilog appSettings write to file in the same server path asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310896/serilog-appsettings-write-to-file-in-the-same-server-path-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score -1):

You can read the environment variable yourself, append your app specific name, and then pass that to the WriteTo directory.

```
var baseDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_FOLDER");
var logPath = Path.Join(baseDirectory, "app1logs.json");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(logPath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thank you. for the quick response.  If I use the above solution, can I continue to modify logger behavior using the configuration file e.g.restrictedToMinimumLevel OR retainedFileCountLimit etc.

Comment: We need to be able to use environment variable in appsettings.json (json) file, just like it's enabled in the appsettings.config (XML) files.